# Set of all p-times differentiable functions is vectorspace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm stuck at the very basic and trivial task which is to prove that the set $M:=C^p(a,b)$ of all p-times differentiable functions $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ form a vector space, whereas the set $M$ is equipped with addition and scalar multiplication, i.e.
for $f,g \in M$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$(f+g)(x) := f(x)+g(x)$

$(\alpha f)(x) := \alpha f(x)$

So I have tried to show some axioms...I know I can use the fact that the continuous functions are a vector space and thus most axioms would be inherited, but I wanted to show it from scratch...

(1)
$f,g, h \in M$

$\frac{d^p}{dx^p}((f+g)(x))+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(h(x))=\frac{d^p}{dx^p}f(x)+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}g(x)+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}h(x)=\frac{d^p}{dx^p}f(x)+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(g(x)+h(x))=\frac{d^p}{dx^p}f(x)+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(g+h)(x)$

(2)
$1\cdot\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))=\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))$

(3)

$\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))+0 = \frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))$

(4)
$\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))+\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(-f(x)) = \frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))+(-\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))=\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x))-\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(f(x)=0$

could someone please check whether my approach works, it looks like something is missing here, everything looks so trivial. (I know I still need to show few more axioms)

Comment: why do you check (2), (3) and (4)? your vector space $C^p$ in question is is readily a vector sapce if it is nonempty (that is, show that there exists a $p$-times continuously differentiable function on $(a,b)$), and if $f,g\in C^p$ implies $f+\lambda g\in C^p$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Your proof of $4$ isn't quite right.  First observe that the additive inverse of $f$ must be $-f$, and then just confirm that if $f$ is $p$-times differentiable, so is $-f$.  You don't need that the $p$th derivative of the sum is in fact $0$ (although that follows, of course).

Comment: @lmaosome: thank you for the hint

Comment: @RobertShore: thank you, could you show me how to do that? i.e. can I just write f(x)-f(x)=0, and since $\forall \lambda$ $\lambda f \in C^p$, also for $\lambda = -1$?

Comment: @Parinn Yes, it really is that simple.